# Find all integer solutions of equation $y = \frac{a+bx}{b-x}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to find all integer solutions for the equation

$y = \frac{a+bx}{b-x}$, where ***a*** and ***b*** are known integer values?

P.S. ***x*** and ***y*** must be integer at the same time

Comment: $$y=-\frac{b(b-x)}{b-x}+\frac{a+b^2}{b-x}$$

Comment: Connected: this [question/answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869251/integer-points-on-a-hyperbola)

Comment: Clear denom's then **complete the product** as explained in the linked dupes.

Comment: I don't agree to close this question on the basis that it is the same as the two cited questions which are very different: here, we have a (special) **parametric** equation...

Comment: @JeanMarie Exactly the same method(s) apply here, e.g. complete the product, as I said. We already have *hundreds* of questions showing how to solve such Diophantine equations (e.g. the linked dupes). Nothing is novel here - see [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242)

Answer (score 2):

First multiply denominator to other side : $0 = yx + bx - by + a = (x-b)(y+b) + a + b^2$

$(x-b)(y+b) = -(a+b^2)$

Then all you need is to write RHS as multiplication of 2 integers: $-(a+b^2) = mn$ and then get 2 solutions $(m+b, n-b)$ and $(n+b, m-b)$ for all different $(m, n)$ pairs.

Corner case:
$a = -b^2$, then all $(x,-b)$ is solution except $x=b$ since function is not defined at $x=b$

Comment: @JeanMarie we are doing $xy +bx - by - b^2 + a + b^2 = (x-b)(y+b) + a + b^2 = 0$

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I erase my remark.

Comment: Deserved to be the answer to this problem!

Comment: @Snowflake with your pseudo, are you completely objective towards Snowball :) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have never encountered this young man